# Convert Word files (.doc | .docx) to PDF, on a Rails 3 app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, converters

*Before you close this as dupe: I have read quite a lot of questions on SO, and none was fitting all my requirements.*

I'm looking for a solution to **convert Word files (`.doc` or `.docx`) to pdf**.

The environment is a Rails 3 application, hosted on heroku.
The solution must be deployable there.

The files are sensitive, so I can't use a 3rd party service.

If possible, I would prefer a real conversion, not a page by page conversions to images.

I have seen a few projects (for example [proselytism](https://github.com/itkin/proselytism)) enabling this, but where libreoffice must be installed. I doubt this would be possible on heroku, but I would love to be proven wrong.

---

I might be crying for the moon, so…

if no solution fits the requirements, it would be ok to imagine *creative* solutions.
For example, a java converter running in an instance somewhere, working on `.doc` file uploaded to Amazon S3.

However, for architectural simplicity, maintainability and my own sanity, I would prefer to stay away from that.

Comment: "The files are sensitive, so I can't use a 3rd party service." 

Heroku is a 3rd party service. You're already trusting someone else with your data if you build this app.

Comment: @jdl I knew I would get this comment, but didn't want to pollute my question. The app must be uploaded somewhere, so heroku or any other host solution, it's the same. And in my case, data is safer with heroku than on a server that I manage myself.

Comment: "Document converter, text and image extractor using OpenOffice headless server (JOD or PYOD converter), pdf_tools and net_pbm" what's the problem with including the binary in heroku just as most people do with wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Out of blue - can't you write a simple ruby script that would run as a worker on a regular workstation and convert files in given dir (and later even upload them to s3)? This fits security, local box can have any setup you could possibly imagine. Wild guess of course.

Comment: The other is to go for amazon aws instead of heroku - that requires more work.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel include binary on heroku: if it works, absolutely no problem. Will look into it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it if best solution

Comment: worker on regular workstation: would prefer to avoid admin sys work, aws is ok.

Comment: @Guillaume I couldn't find if anyone has done it before and it seems using binary is not so easy (theres no single file to attach) so I don't think it's a real answer

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?